# Linear independence for infinite-dimensional spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $H$ be a separable Hilbert space with a (not orthogonal) basis $\{h_n\}$. What is the notion of linear independence of these basis elements $h_n$? Is it that $$\sum_{n=1}^{k}a_jh_j = 0$$ implies $a_j=0$ for all finite $k$? Is it even true?

Answer (score 2):

If there was no topological struction on $H$, then yes, linear independence means that no vector in the set is a finite linear combination of the others.

In a Hilbert space it means that $h_i \notin \overline{\mathrm{Span} \{h_j|\ j \not= i\}}$ for all $i$. That is, there exists no *sequence* of finite linear combinations of elements of $\{h_j |, j \not= i\}$ that converges to $h_i$.

This reflects a fundamental difference in the use of the word "basis" in the two different contexts.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand correct: let $H$ be a Hilbert space. Then the definition of linear independence you give in your second paragraph implies linear independence as I "give" it in my OP. I guess both definitions are equivalent though right?

Comment: Let $H = \ell^2(\mathbb R)$. For $n \ge 1$ you can define $h_n = (0,\ldots,0,1,0,\ldots)$ where the $1$ occurs in position $n$, and define $h_0 = (1, \frac 12, \frac 13, \ldots)$. The set $\{h_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ is linearly independent in the first sense but not the second.

Comment: Hmm. If they are not equivalent then it seems to me that your definition of linear independence seems to be unusual. For example http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Hilbert_space "A countable sequence of vectors  is said to be a linearly independent sequence if all its finite subsets are linearly independent " where the finite linear independence is defined as I wrote in the OP.

Comment: Look at it this way. Should $\{h_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ be considered a basis of $\ell^2$? It clearly spans the space and all its finite subsets are linearly independent.

Comment: I agree, it should be considered as a basis. So this suggests to me that linear independence in a infinite-dimensional Hilbert space should be defined as in my OP. Right? Sorry if I am missing something.

Comment: Hi. I was wondering if it is possible to find an infinite sequence in Hilbert space that is both linearly independent and the sum of the elements of the sequence is zero!